# How do i write this in list comprehension in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I want to write a list comprehension that will have print an element out of an array every other element. How do I do so?

```
for item in results:
    record = extract_record(item)
    if record:
        records.append(record)
```

Comment: Give a proper example of what you want.

Comment: List comprehensions comes at a cost when you have an assignment **`[extract_record(item) for item in results if extract_record(item)]`**, here extract_record is invoked twice when it returns a valid record

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Python 3.8 or later you could make use of the assignment expression and do something like

```
records = [record for item in results if (record := extract_record(item))]
```

This avoids having to extract the record twice.

Answer (score 0):

The list comprehension equivalent of the above will be:

```
records = [extract_record(item) for item in results if extract_record(item)]
```

Note that `extract_record()` is needed twice and hence not so useful.